# Need Help on Filtering the json to grab only the values

Tags: php, regex

I want to apply the regex to extract only the values. I am not getting the perfect one any help

```
[{"name":"basket ball"},{"name":"foot ball"},{"name":"sports"}]
```

Comment: If you have an array of objects like that, `array_column` can be handy to get the values from a single key like "name" (after you json_decode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no need for a regex here. Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$string = '[{"name":"basket ball"},{"name":"foot ball"},{"name":"sports"}]';
$data = json_decode($string, true);
```

now you have a normal php array `$data` to get your wanted data from.
like

```
echo $data[0]['name']; // basket ball
```

Comment: How can I print whole array.

Comment: for testing you can use `print_r()` or a `var_dump()`. Otherwise loop through it and output what and how you need it.